# Is there a range of values in the Akaike information criterion (AIC) score that tells us that the model is correct?

Tags: aic, model-evaluation

I know that when choosing a model, the AIC and BIC criteria are considered since the one with the lowest value will be the one corresponding to the best model, however, I would like to know if; Is there a range within the values that tells me if the model is correct ?, and if there is a minimum number of samples for the formation of a model?

Comment: No there is not.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking two questions:

1. Can the actual value of AIC (or BIC) determined from the fit one model to a dataset give you any information about whether that model is correct?

No.

The value of AIC will depend on the units the data are measured in. If the data are weights, changing from pounds to kilograms will change the AIC (and BIC), so the actual values of AIC or BIC cannot be interpreted. In contrast, the difference between AIC (or BIC) determined for the fit of two different models can be interpreted (and will be the same regardless of what units the data are expressed in).

2. "Is there a minimum sample size for the formation of a model?"

This is too vague, too general, too open-ended, I think, for there to be any useful answer.

Comment: About the point #2, I wonder if any hypothetical scenario could be mentioned in which the sample size may matter, and scenario in which it does not. That might be better than criticizing the question (?).

Comment: @rraadd88. It seems you have a different question in mind. I'd suggest posting it, with details, as a new question.